# program not displaying desired string representation of object

Tags: java

I made a program in java that should return all the orders made to a provider.
Instead of displaying the id of the orders, it displays sakila.entity.Order@883357, where sakila.entity is the package that contains Order.java and Order.hbm.xml.
I think the problem is in the method displayResult(). Maybe somebody can figure it out.
Thanks a lot!

Here is the program:

```
package sakila.ui;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import sakila.entity.Comanda;
import sakila.entity.Furnizor;
import sakila.util.HibernateUtil;


public class SearchOrders extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public SearchOrders() {
    initComponents();
}


private void queryButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    //if (!idProviderTextField.getText().trim().equals(""))
            runQueryBasedOnIdFurnizor();
}                                            

private void runQueryBasedOnIdProvider(){
    executeHQLQuery("from Provider c where c.idprovider like '" +  idProvider.getText() + "%'" );

}

 private void executeHQLQuery(String hql){
    try{
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    org.hibernate.Query q = session.createQuery(hql);
    List resultList = q.list();
    displayResult(resultList);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    }catch (HibernateException he){
        he.printStackTrace();
    }
}

  private void displayResult(List resultList){
    Vector<String> tableHeaders = new Vector<String>();
    Vector tableData = new Vector();
    tableHeaders.add("IdOrder");

    for (Object o : resultList){
        Provider p = (Provider) o;

        Set<Order> c = p.getOrder();
        Iterator it = c.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Object element = it.next();
            System.out.println(element);
            Vector <Object> oneRow = new Vector <Object>();
            oneRow.add(element);

        tableData.add(oneRow);
        }
    }
   resultTable1.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(tableData, tableHeaders)); 
}


public static void main(String args[]) {
        public void run() {
            new SearchOrders().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JTextField idProviderTextField;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JButton queryButton1;
private javax.swing.JTable resultTable1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Here is the class Order.java

```
package sakila.entity;
```

// Generated Apr 9, 2012 10:19:40 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Order implements java.io.Serializable {

```
 private int idorder;
 private Client client;
 private Depozit warehouse;
 private Furnizor provider;
 private Integer idproduct;
 private Integer unitmas;
 private Integer quantity;
 private Set comdetals = new HashSet(0);
 private Set facturas = new HashSet(0);

public Order() {
}


public Order(int idorder) {
    this.idorder = idorder;
}
public Order(int idorder, Client client, Warehouse warehouse, Provider provider, Integer idproduct, Integer unitmas, Integer quantity, Set comdetals, Set facturas) {
   this.idorder = idorder;
   this.client = client;
   this.warehouse = warehouse;
   this.provider = provider;
   this.idproduct = idproduct;
   this.unitmas = unitmas;
   this.quantity = quantity;
   this.comdetals = comdetals;
   this.facturas = facturas;
}

public int getIdorder() {
    return this.idorder;
}

public void setIdorder(int idorder) {
    this.idorder = idorder;
}
public Client getClient() {
    return this.client;
}

public void setClient(Client client) {
    this.client = client;
}
public Warehouse getWarehouse() {
    return this.warehouse;
}

public void setWarehouse(Warehouse warehouse) {
    this.warehouse = warehouse;
}
public Provider getProvider() {
    return this.provider;
}

public void setProvider(Provider provider) {
    this.provider = provider;
}
public Integer getIdproduct() {
    return this.idproduct;
}

public void setIdproduct(Integer idproduct) {
    this.idproduct = idproduct;
}
public Integer getUnitmas() {
    return this.unitmas;
}

public void setUnitmas(Integer unitmas) {
    this.unitmas = unitmas;
}
public Integer getQuantity() {
    return this.quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(Integer quantity){
    this.quantity = quantity;
}
public Set getComdetals() {
    return this.comdetals;
}

public void setComdetals(Set comdetals) {
    this.comdetals = comdetals;
}
public Set getFacturas() {
    return this.facturas;
}

public void setFacturas(Set facturas) {
    this.facturas = facturas;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post the code for Order.java (if my answer doesn't give you enough help)?

Comment: The default `toString()` representation for an object is the object's fully qualified class name followed by @ followed by the object's hashCode. So what you're seeing is what you should expect to see, unless you give the object's class a decent `public String toString()` method which returns a String that shows the information that you want the object to display. 1+ to @matt for his correct and succinct answer.

Comment: @matt do you have an idea how I could use that toString() method in order to see my id displayed and not the hashcode? Maybe you could help me when you have time. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Right now the `System.out.println(element);` line is just using the default `toString()` method, which prints out some internal code of the `Order` object.

Your `Order` class would need to override the `toString()` method for it to print out the id of the order.

Or it would probably be better to change your iterator code to read:

```
Iterator<Order> it = c.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Order element = it.next();
    System.out.println(element.getIdorder());
```

That way you don't have to write a `toString()` method just for this one case. Usually when you override `toString()` you want it to print out a text representation of the full object: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29

Comment: Thank you for your advice @matt. But I would appreciate if you could show me how to use the toString() method on my example. I posted also the Order.java.

Comment: Edited with more info and a better way.